Created menu item in NX through .rtb, .tbr and .men files to call Windows Forms application, but it is not able to read the session object?
Problem statement: Created Custom Toolbar and menu item in NX through .rtb, .tbr and .men files and configured it for button action to call Windows Forms application. But the application is not able to read the session object even though the drawing sheet is present?
Created a simple Windows Forms application using NX Open, which I call in Siemens NX from user command.
Application Functionality: Contains a button "button 1". Upon button click it checks if any drawing sheet is open/available and displays the message accordingly if Drawing Sheet is available or not?
Code Logic:
NXOpen.Session theSession = NXOpen.Session.GetSession();

NXOpen.Part workPart = theSession.Parts.Work;

NXOpen.Part displayPart = theSession.Parts.Display;

var drawingSheet = displayPart?.DrawingSheets;

if (drawingSheet != null)

{

  MessageBox.Show("Drawing Sheet Available!");

}

else

{

  MessageBox.Show("Drawing sheet is not available!");

}

This application is working fine and it's functionality is also working fine when I call from User Command which I manually added to ribbon tab user command and customize the button action to execute my .exe file of Windows application.
I have a project requirement where I had to automate the process of adding user commands manually and customize the button action to run the application. Therefore I followed below process.
NXMenu folder contains two sub folders : application, startup
startup folder: It contains my_programs.rtb, custom_toolbar.tbr and custom_menu.men files.
application folder: It contains the application(macro) files.
Steps followed to run these files:
Placed the NXMenu folder under the C drive (C:\NXMenu).
Created a new System variable UGII_USER_DIR and its value as C:\NXMenu
Open the NX application.
Based on the commands present in my_programs.rtb, custom_toolbar.tbr and custom_menu.men files NX application now opens with a new tab "Test Custom Macro" and the tab contains a new User Command Item "Test User Command". Upon click on this user command item it runs the macro (WinForms application) .exe file.
Until here it's working as expected.
But the functionality of this macro is not working fine.
Issue:
As per the code logic we should be able to get the session object through NXOpen.Session theSession = NXOpen.Session.GetSession();
But the macro was not able to read the session object even though the drawing sheet is opened. The document is fully loaded.
We are facing this issue only when we add the macro with above steps. But when I add the user command manually in NX application and configure the macro and execute it, it is working fine.
Also, the macro is taking little long time to load.
Macro logic:
Macro which is a simple .NET Windows Forms application is just a form which contains a button. This button has functionality of upon click event it checks the whether any session object is present or not and displays the message accordingly.
Note:
Macro is working fine when tried to execute through conventional way File --> Execute --> NX Open --> provide .exe file.
Or by adding the macro through Customize, add new User Command and configure it to execute .exe file.
In both the ways macro is working fine.
Also, it's a signed dot net exe file. It's a Signed assembly file.
Could you please check why we are not able to read the session object if we are adding menu item through the above followed steps method. We wanted to add menu item through that way since we had to automate the process of adding menu item instead of doing it manually.
my_programs.rtb file:
!
!
!Custom Toolbar File
!
TITLE Test Custom Macro
VERSION 170
DOCK TOP


BUTTON IMPORT_BUTTON
LABEL Import
BITMAP $UGII_USER_DIR\application\icons\iso-filled.bmp

GROUP custom_toolbar.tbr

BUTTON NEW_BUTTON

custom_toolbar.tbr file:
TITLE Drawings
VERSION 170

BUTTON CUSTOM_BUTTON_1
LABEL Test User Command

custom_menu.men file:
! Customer menu file
!
! Contains button definitions to be used in
! toolbars and Ribbon files
!
VERSION 120

EDIT UG_GATEWAY_MAIN_MENUBAR


TOP_MENU
    CASCADE_BUTTON CUSTOMER_MENU
    LABEL Test Customer Menu
END_OF_TOP_MENU

MENU CUSTOMER_MENU
    BUTTON CUSTOM_BUTTON_1
    LABEL Test User Command   
    ACTIONS "C:\NXMenu\application\WindowsFormsApp1.exe"

END_OF_MENU

Application code:
Program.cs file:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

Form1.cs file:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NXOpen;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {           
                NXOpen.Session theSession = NXOpen.Session.GetSession();
                NXOpen.Part workPart = theSession.Parts.Work;
                NXOpen.Part displayPart = theSession.Parts.Display;

                var drawingSheet = displayPart?.DrawingSheets;
                if (drawingSheet != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Drawing Sheet Available!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Drawing sheet is not available!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public static int GetUnloadOption(string dummy)
        {
            return (int)NXOpen.Session.LibraryUnloadOption.Immediately;
        }
    }
}


Please post the code of the whole application. How is the window being initialized, unload options etc.

Hi @Hanebu,
I have added the application code (Program.cs file and Form1.cs file) in the above question towards the end of the problem statement.

Hi, if you compile the program as a .dll instead of a .exe, and load it with CTRL+U (execute user function), does it work? If yes, changing the file extension should also work if you load it via a toolbar. If you want to use it via an external application (e.g. exe), you must load a remoting server dll on NX startup (see remoting example in your ugopen directory), and connect to this library from your exe.

Oh, and i am not 100% sure if you can use .NET, to my latest knowledge .NET Framework 4.x should work.
